# How to Install SSL Certificate on VPS using EHCP

Tags: ssl, vps

I bought SSL Certificate, the CSR and Private Key Codes have been mailed to me.
My VPS has EHCP Panel installed on it. how should I proceed, in order to install the SSL on my server.

I edited the **server.csr** and **server.key** with the codes sent to me respectively. But it still doesn't show ***https.***

Thanks.

Comment: What you did till now?

Comment: I  edited the server.csr and server.key with the codes sent to me respectively. But it still doesn't show https.

Comment: Information like that, should be injected by **EDIT** to your question. This will help others with your question.

Comment: I  edited the server.csr and server.key with the codes sent to me respectively. But it still doesn't show https. @timiTao